# javascript regex replace sequential ampersand symbol to semicolon

Tags: javascript, regex

How to replace sequential ampersand symbol leaving single ampersand untouched. Below is the script I tried which replaces every ampersand into double semicolon.

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">Women->Lingerie & Sleepwear->Bras&& Women->Western Wear->Shorts & Capris&& Women->Lingerie & Sleepwear->Nightwear & Nighties</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace('&amp', ";");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say sequential. Will they have spaces between them?? It would be better if you update your question with the sequential ampersand too

Comment: No. There will be no space between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way would be to define a global regex (with a `/g` flag) that contains `&amp;` twice:

```
str.replace(/&amp;&amp;/g, ";"); // replace exactly "&amp;&amp;" anywhere in the string with ";"
```

Running sample:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
  var res = str.replace(/&amp;&amp;/g, ";");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">
  Women->Lingerie & Sleepwear->Bras&& Women->Western Wear->Shorts & Capris&& Women->Lingerie & Sleepwear->Nightwear & Nighties</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

or use a `{min,max}` regex pattern as [Alex R specified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35953822/3928341)

Comment: if its this way then there is no need of regex at all.. he can just do a string replace without regex. `str.replace("&amp;&amp;", ";")`

Comment: Thought of that too but that will actually only replace the first occurence

Answer (score 2):

You need the {min[,max]} modifier in your regex statement:

```
str.replace(/(&amp;){2}/g, ";")
```

Comment: Quick note, he actually needs to replace `&amp;` because html uses character references

Comment: Also I think OP wants **exactly** two occurrences, so you probably want `{2}` instead of `{2,}` and you don't want `[]` because that matches **any** character within `[]`. Something like this would work: `str.replace(/(&amp;){2}/g, ";")`